# Use the Central Limit Theorem to determine the critical region corresponding to significance level

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1;...;X_n$ be a random sample from a $U(0;\theta)$ distribution with $\theta>0$. Define the random variable $T = \overline{X}_n$. 
Let n= 144. You want to test $H_0$: $\theta= 12$ against $H_1$: $\theta \neq 12$ and use $T$ as your test statistic. Suppose $\overline{x}_{144} = 6.5$. 
Use the Central Limit Theorem to determine the critical region corresponding to significance level $\alpha = 0.05$ and report your conclusion about the null hypothesis.

In order to calculate the critical region (value of T where we reject $H_0$ in favour of $H_1$) I have to determine the critical values, but how can I do it? Can someone help me giving some hints, Thanks!

Update: (this is what I think I should do, where I'm wrong?) 
$P(T\geq C_1)=0.05$ From the $N(0,1)$ table $C=1.64$. 
$P(T\leq C_1)=0.95$ From the $N(0,1)$ table $C=-1.64$. 
$Z = \frac{\overline{X_n}-\mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}$ 
$\frac{\overline{X_n}-6}{\frac{12}{\sqrt{144}}}=1.64\:\overline{X_n}=7.64\:K=(7.64;\infty)$ 
$\frac{\overline{X_n}-6}{\frac{12}{\sqrt{144}}}=-1.64\:\overline{X_n}=4.36\:K=(\infty;4.36)$

Comment: Are you sure that $T = X_n$ and not $T = \overline{X_n}$?

Comment: Yes you are right, fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints:

- According to CLT you have $Z = \frac{\overline{X_n}-\mu_{\theta}}{\frac{\sigma_{\theta}}{\sqrt{n}}} \stackrel{\approx}{\sim} N(0,1)$.
- $H_0: \theta = 12 \stackrel{X \sim U(0,\theta)}{\Longrightarrow} \mu_{\theta}=\frac{\theta}{2} = 6$ and $\sigma_{\theta}^2 =\frac{\theta^2}{12}$.
- As $H_1: \theta \neq 12$, you have a 2-tailed test and find the $z$-score by
  $$P(z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\leq Z \leq z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}) = 1- \alpha = 0.95$$.
- The critical region results by backwards calculation from $z < z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ and $z > z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints.
Based on the correct result the critical values should be different, why? How can I calculate different critical values?
Answer: $K= (\infty;5.43)\infty(6.57;\infty)$

Comment: Because the sample mean may deviate too much to the left or to the right from the expected mean. So, there must be a lower critical value and an upper one. (2-tailed test).

Comment: Thanks, I update the question with my calculations, where I'm wrong?

Comment: You forgot to take the square root while calculating $\sigma$. It is $\sqrt{12} = 2\sqrt{3}$.
I got the critical values as $x_L \approx 5.4342$ and $x_R \approx 6.5658$.

Comment: Besides this, you need to distribute $\alpha = 0.05$ equally on both sides. So, the $z$-scores are $z_{0.025} \approx -1.96$ and $z_{0.975} \approx 1.96$.

Comment: I adjusted the indices of the $z$-scores for more clarity.
Btw., I will be off for a while. Will check in here later.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, now it's clear!
I have a question, we can say that is a two-tailed p-value because $H_1 \neq value$ right, and so we use $z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$, in case of a one-tailed p-value we just use $z_{\alpha}$?

Comment: @FabioTaccaliti 
You are right concerning the usage of $z_{\alpha}$ and $z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ in 1- and 2-tailed tests. But the $p$ value itself is related to a specific sample and its $z$-score say $z_{test}$. It says how probable an even more deviating test result is provided that $H_0$ is true: In the 2-tailed case you have: $p = P(|Z| > z_{test}\; | \; H_0)$. So, for example, the boundaries $x_L$ and $x_R$ of the critical region have a $p$-value of $0.05$.